# I got aborted request in my post request using axios

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

I am trying to make a post request, but I always get the error:

```
Error: "Request aborted"
    createError createError.js:16
    handleAbort xhr.js:73

   [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...   log.js:24
```

I am using react.js in this code, I am new to it. I am getting this error with and without my backend, so I believe my error is on the front. Also, I have tested my backend and all routes are working fine. My post request as well as my axios configuration file is given below. Can you guys help me? I have already tried some variation of the below code, for example, I tried sending as an URL in axios only /cadastro instead of the whole path.

Post request:

```
  const [nome, setNome] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [cpf, setCpf] = useState("");
  const [senha, setSenha] = useState("");
  const [rg, setRg] = useState("");
  const [data_nascimento, setDataNascimento] = useState("");

  async function save(){

    try{
      await api.post('http://localhost:5000/cadastro', {
        nome,
        cpf,
        email,
        rg,
        data_nascimento,
        senha
      })
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

axios:

```
import Axios from 'axios';

const api = Axios.create({
  baseURL: 'localhost:5000',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  crossdomain: true
});

api.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  // Do something before request is sent
  console.log(config)
  return config;
}, function (error) {
  console.log(error)
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

export default api;
```

EDIT 1: I tried what ludwiger told me to do, but I got the same error.

Comment: Can you try adding the http:// to the baseUrl

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting a `baseUrl` in the config then you need to use the relative path in the call

```
await api.post('/cadastro', {...
```